# jQuery: Optimize code (learning case)

Tags: jquery

I have to admit, I came up with this solution by pure intuition from seeing many jQuery scripts during all the time I've been experimenting and learning on my own.

Since I don't have anyone to ask in person these kind of questions, that's why I come here for help and guidance.

--

Inspired by [Wufoo's plans' forms](https://secure.wufoo.com/signup/1/) where the row you need to focus is highlighted while filling out the form, I created this script (I am not a jQuery or JavaScript guru, I'm still learning and practicing):

```
//Improve usability by highlighting the row the user needs to focus on:
$(function() {
        //When input element has focus
        $('input').focus(function(){
            //Add the class to its corresponding row
            $(this).parent().parent('.row').addClass('focus'),
                //And when it loses focus
                $('input').blur(function(){
                    //Remove the class
                    $(this).parent().parent('.row').removeClass('focus');
                });
        });
});
```

So I was wondering if this script has a way of being written better or optimized/shorten in any way. If not, and the way I wrote it's Ok, that's fine, all I'd like to learn is ways of optimizing code when possible, that's all.

I created a **[Demo in Codepen](http://codepen.io/rzea/pen/mBbjs)** if you want to check it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did not know about http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - Thanks a lot for that. Gave you an upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
//Improve usability by highlighting the row the user needs to focus on:
$(function() {
        $('input').focus(function(){
            $(this).closest('.row').addClass('focus'); // Change here                    
        }).blur(function(){ // Change here
           $(this).closest('.row').removeClass('focus'); // Change here
        });
});
```

Or even shorter!

```
$(function(){
    $("input").on("focus blur", function(){
        $(this).closest(".row").toggleClass("focus");
    });
});
```

You did 1 thing totally wrong!! Each time you focus you bind a new blur to each input!

Comment: Like the super-short version, very neat :)

Comment: This is great, thanks for the help :) Demo has been updated as well. - Regarding what I did 'so' wrong, what does "binding a new blur to each input" mean? Thanks again.

Comment: You did a `$("input").blur(fu` which is a new bind within a `$("input").focus(`. So each time you focus. You do a new bind. Which means if you focus 1 input 2 times. You got 2 blur events. If you focus 1 more, you got 3 blur events etc. You don't want to do that. So don't bind within a bind. You can just bind the blur beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

Code looks good. The only changes I'd make are to use `closest()` instead of chaining `parent()` calls, as if you change the DOM around you would need to change your jQuery code. Also, I'd move the `blur()` handler outside of the `focus()` handler. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('input')
        .focus(function() {
            $(this).closest('.row').addClass('focus');
        })
        .blur(function() {
            $(this).closest('.row').removeClass('focus');
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about using `.closest()`, I had a feeling using double `.parent()` wasn't the best way. Your code worked great but Niel's short version was right on the money. Gave you an upvote though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to keep my even handlers and event binding separated. This is convenient to do with the `.on()` which actually binds the event to all the current and future `.row` elements unlike the `.focus()` which only binds the event on the rows you had on the page when the binding happened.

This way you don't need to wrap your code into `$(function(){});` either. And you can have the event binding in an included .js file instead of mixing your jQuery with your markup.

Additionally, use `.closest()` instead of `.parent().parent()` because it won't break if you choose to change your structure a bit. Provided that your `.row` is still there.

```
var onRowFocus = function(){
    $('.row').removeClass('focus');
    $(this).closest('.row').addClass('focus');
};

$('.row').on('focus', 'input', onRowFocus);
```

Also, you don't need to bind the `.blur` event at all. Simply remove the `focus` class from all rows before you add it to the one on focus. Less event handlers, less code, easier to maintain.

Comment: Oh, well, this is quite nice as well and works great. Will consider the lesson here and your explanations. Gave you an upvote. Thanks a lot.